# Rails association blocks affect query scope. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models in a Rails 5.1 app. Master is the primary model, and Item belongs to it. For a special use case, I have a need to override the #build method for `master.items.build`. Inside this new build method I have to make a query to check for certain conditions in other items.

When doing this, I experience some unexpected (by me) behaviour, such that the association block appears to alter the scope of the queries.

**master.rb**

```
class Master < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :items,  inverse_of: :master do
    def build att=nil
      item = self.new(master: proxy_association.owner)      
      item.description1 = self.where(master_id: nil).to_sql
      item.description2 = self.unscoped.where(master_id: nil).to_sql
      item
    end
  end

end
```

**item.rb**

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :master

  before_create -> {
    self.description1 = self.class.where(master_id: nil).to_sql
    self.description2 = self.class.unscoped.where(master_id: nil).to_sql
  }

end
```

**master_test.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'

class MasterTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  test "master build outside association works as expected" do

    m = Master.create! name: 'Bob'
    item = Item.create master: m, name: 'Wall'

    puts "Master: #{m}"
    puts "self.where(master_id: nil).to_sql"
    puts item.description1
    puts "self.unscoped.where(master_id: nil).to_sql"
    puts item.description2

    # Flawed understanding would expect the queries to be the same
    assert item.description1 == item.description2
  end

  test "master association blocks add an unexpected scope" do

    m = Master.create! name: 'Bob'
    item = m.items.build name: 'Wall'

    puts "Master: #{m}"
    puts "self.where(master_id: nil).to_sql"
    puts item.description1
    puts "self.unscoped.where(master_id: nil).to_sql"
    puts item.description2

    # Flawed understanding would expect the queries to be the same
    assert item.description1 == item.description2
  end
end
```

In short, the result of the first test acts as expected. Both unscoped and standard queries act as expected.The result of the second test, calling the same queries inside the association block result in:

```
Master: #<Master:0x0055c3ee11b770>
self.where(master_id: nil).to_sql
SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."master_id" = 980190963 AND "items"."master_id" IS NULL
self.unscoped.where(master_id: nil).to_sql
SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."master_id" IS NULL
```

I have not seen this documented anywhere and am hoping that somebody could point me to the reason for this automatic scoping inside the association block, and where it is explained. I would accept it without question, but this behaviour appears to have changed at some point (based on an app having tests that have started to fail). I have also experienced it in an older version 4.2.9 app, where I know it worked without this scoping in the past.

Here is a GitHub repo with a test app if needed to reproduce: https://github.com/philayres/test_assoc_blocks

Should be as simple as `rails db:migrate` and `rake test` to demonstrate it.

I'm open to ideas and explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm not understanding this correctly:

```
m = Master.create! name: 'Bob'
item = m.items.build name: 'Wall'

puts "Master: #{m}"
puts "self.where(master_id: nil).to_sql"
puts item.description1
puts "self.unscoped.where(master_id: nil).to_sql"
puts item.description2

# Flawed understanding would expect the queries to be the same
assert item.description1 == item.description2
```

In this case, you are passing a scope to the build method:

```
item = m.items.build name: 'Wall'
```

This scope is Item.where(master_id: m.id).

Inside the overwritten build method you then do:

```
item.description1 = self.where(master_id: nil).to_sql
```

self will be the scoped instance of the Class here - which will become

```
Item.where(master_id: m.id).where(master_id: nil).to_sql
```

For the second method you have

```
self.unscoped.where(master_id: nil).to_sql
```

which will remove the first scope, and then apply the where clause.  I'm not sure why you'd want to call

```
m.items
```

If you specifically do not want the items associated to m.

To verify this, try examining what

```
self.to_sql
```

and self actually are inside the block.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this. The issue is that I am seeing a scope being applied that I have not explicitly defined. The magical scope appears to be based on the parent 'master' object from which I'm building. The query becomes implicitly scoped as: `SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."master_id" = 980190963 [...]`. Based on your answer so far, I don't yet see why this scope suddenly appears. I'm looking for an explanation of why this scope is applied just inside an association block when I see it nowhere else.

Comment: Sorry, aren't you seeing it when you call m.items?  That would be what is applying this scope.

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand why that is applying a scope. If I use a m.items outside of a block there is no scope. Is there an explanation somewhere documented that explains why a scope is applied in an association block?

Comment: What do you mean that it won't apply a scope otherwise?  Try doing m.items.to_sql.  By definition m.items is Items.where(m_id = m.id).

Comment: I suppose that makes sense. I think I have never noticed the scope before, since mostly I work with the result of m.items, rather than seeing the implicit scope being set as I do inside the block. I think I just assumed that m.items generated a magic ActiveQuery resultset with the appropriate where clause, rather than messing with the scope. Strange (or worrying) that my test suite has only just noticed this. Thanks for your help, I'll mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: But that's really all the scope is - addition of a where clause to narrow down the resultset.

Comment: I get the way result sets can be chained. But typically a single chain of result sets does not impact other queries in the way a scope does. To me, the association and my models did not have scope explicitly specified, so it was strange to expect a scope to be applied to a completely unrelated query. It seems from what you are saying that is just the way things operate. I think this is one of those cases where Rails documentation could help out a bit more. Though I equally understand this is an unusual case. Thanks for your insights.

Comment: I think you need to look at it as a class method, in which case you're operating on a collection you're passing in - in this case that collection (self) is m.items.

If I have a class method (self.some_function) and I call Model.scope_one.scope_two.some_function, obviously self is going to be Model.scope_one.scope_two.

You are calling build on the collection m.items.  For my sanity, I also tested m.items.another_scope.build, and self was m.items.another_scope as expected.

Comment: I think that is a reasonable way to look at it. Hopefully I'll remember that the next time I attempt this. Thanks!